# Scroll % in Vim cmd line?

Tags: vim

I apologize for the n00bish question, however it's one of those where the key terms are too generic to find an answer very easily.

Basically on all my Linux installations, opening any file in Vim displays the vertical scroll % in the bottom right corner of the cmd line.

I'm currently running Windows, and I've installed the vanilla Vim 64bit installation. (I'm using console Vim rather than gVim). Currently there is no information in my cmd line besides a mode indicator when I switch from normal mode. How can I get the scroll % there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within `vim`:

```
:set ruler
```

To get it permanently, in your `vim` configuration file, add it without the `:`:

```
set ruler
```

Answer (score 2):

To *temporarily* get it back, use

```
CTRL-G
```

It may show up in the bottom right as you request, or it may be closer to centered... actually at the right end of the left-justified bit of info that comes up on the lowest line of the window.

Note: This also gets you the row number and column number.  It disappears as soon as you enter some other command that typically causes a visible change to that status line.

To *permanently* get it back, use

```
:set ruler
```

or add a line with `set ruler` to your config file (usually .exrc, .vimrc, or .gvimrc)